# Allow copying and deny replication

Tags: lotus-notes, address-book

How can I allow copying and deny replication for the addressbook for author access? 
Lotus Notes version 8.5.2
Is it possible in someway `?

Comment: Why is copying allowed? Is it worth making special function to make copy as privileged user (agent) and send the copy by mail? You can allow replication and manage replication formula at server to not allow incoming changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can specifically disable replication while still allowing copying, but it shouldn't matter. Just set the default to author with only read public documents and replicate or copy documents, unless your end users have a need to create or delete documents directly in there themselves. Having create/delete/write all unchecked should prevent them from messing up your good replica of the db.